# Target a div with a certain nested class

Tags: html, css

I've got the following code several times on a page:

```
<div>
    <input class="entry">
</div>
```

I want to target the div tag through css without creating a class or id.  Is this possible?

I tried `div.entry { foo }`  and `.entry div {foo}`  neither seemed to work.

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS yet. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: It's not possible through css in the way you describe / hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not targeting the div with that CSS, you'll need to select the parent of the input that has the entry class. However, there's no way of doing this in current CSS but with selector specs of CSS4, which could be done as follows:

```
div! > input.entry { foo }
```

AFAIK, there's no browsers supporting this yet, so you'll have to use JavaScript.

Comment: I ended up adding a class to the div.  Thanks for the help though.